# How would I start a new paragraph in a mobile linkedin app in android device?

Tags: linkedin-api

When writing a message in LinkedIn on android devise, the 'enter' button sends the message. How would I start a new paragraph?

Comment: I haven't figured it out either, but it's really annoying. you can change this setting in the browser on a pc, but not in the android app or android chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the keyboard that your app is using. You will need to go into the app settings and change to a US keyboard to allow for the enter to be used as the enter key instead of send.

This answer was given to me by a LinkedIn community expert Julie

I have followed her instructions on my Android phone and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not work on Samsung Galaxy A5. 
I removed all lenguages and keyboards other than English (US) and it still sends instead of insert  (break paragraph).
A working solution would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is a comment/additional question not an answer.